# Ngrx state mutability

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, store

I am currently trying to learn how to use Ngrx store and i'm having some trouble understanding something :
In my app I have a state which is an Array of ingredient Objects in the form : {name : string , amount : number}.

Now when I try to add a new object I want to check if an object with the same name already exists and if so then I simply add the old amount with the new amount and that's it.

but when I tried to do the following :

1. I copy the old ingredients to a new array using the spread operator:
   newIngredients = ...state.ingredients;
2. I get the index of the existing object with the same name
3. I simply change the amount property on the new array :
   newIngredients[index].amount = newAmount;

Here I get an error that says I can't change the amount propery because it is readonly.
but when I used services instead of ngrx store I was able to do it without any problems.

It only worked once I copied the existing object using the spread operator and then changed its amount and then put the new object instead of the old one in the array.

Why is that happening? Does the store returns some sort of immutable set of objects in the array?

Comment: State in Ngrx is immutable (frozen). You need to make a copy of the object first, then change the value.

Answer (score 0):

in Redux store can be modified only through **actions** and then will trigger pure function **reducers** to operate on your immutable store  which make it the single source of truth. store is set at a whole you can't change a part of it directly. same as

```
Object.freeze(obj);
```

Where we can't obj

```
obj.prop = 1; // this will throw an error
```